# get structure name for that member

Tags: c++, struct

Is there any method or solution in achieving this?
I have structures defined like

```
struct Chassis1
{ string IndicatorLED;
  string AssetTag;
};

struct Chassis2
{ string HostName;
  string PowerState;
};

struct Chassis3
{ string ChassisType;
  int IntrusionNumber;
};
```

I want code that gives the structure name under which that member is defined.
For example if HostName is input, then it should give Chassis2 as output.

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism for addressing members by their name at run-time.

Comment: No, you'll have to write the code for that yourself. Also it sounds like a strange scenario, why do you need this?

Comment: Wow. I was about to say this question sounds curiously similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781581/find-in-which-structure-that-particular-member-is-defined but now that other question has gained actual code samples, and it seems to be identical. Is this some weird homework exercise?

Comment: My actual problem is to get value for certain key in JSON response. The value for that key is defined in one of many structures defined as shown in question. I should implement a function, which should take that key as input and give corresponding value of key output by searching all available structures. This is actual requirement. Now please help in solving this

Comment: C++ doesn't support dynamic typing, so knowing the name is useless

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc please look into my previous comment.. that is the actual problem. can you suggest any idea to get this

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ doesn't provide this kind of built-in reflection. If you want this functionality, you need to code it yourself. Besides, your problem is underspecified: What if the same member name appears in several different structures (possibly even structures of the same name but in different namespaces)?

But this whole question smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): Even if you could get `"Chassis2"` at runtime, what would you do with it? Having a class name in a string doesn't seem directly useful. In the absence of more context, the direct answer to your question is simply "no".

Comment: My actual problem is to get value for certain key in JSON response. The value for that key is defined in one of many structures defined as shown in question. I should implement a function, which should take that key as input and give corresponding value of key output by searching all available structures. This is actual requirement. Now please help in solving this.

Comment: @SundeepKumarGorantla That description makes no sense. It also has nothing to do with getting the name of a class in a string. We might be in XYZ territory here.